# How do I prevent CloudFront from caching for a specific User Agent? (Zabbix web monitoring)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, monitoring, zabbix

I configured Zabbix web scenarios for monitoring WordPress sites. The problem is that CloudFront caches it and returns HTTP code 200 without referring to the origin.

To solve this, I came up with an idea that I might be able to disable caching for a specific User Agent by using Lambda@Edge or CloudFront functions or something, but I'm not sure about it.

I need to use actual domain names because the origin (ALB + EC2) uses name-based virtualhost, so I cannot directly query the DNS name of the origin.

Is there any common solution or best practice in the case like this?

Comment: maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964794/aws-cloudfront-forward-user-agent-but-dont-cache-against-it

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that is a different problem.  The question above is asking about cache key, but my question is about conditional cache control.